# Mounted encrypted disk images are accessible by other users

Tags: user-account, dmg

Is it normal that mounted encrypted disk images appear on the other user's desktop as well if you have two different users at the same computer? This phenomena has been around for some time now. I could not get rid of it by reinstalling the system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal.

You can use the procedure [given here](https://serverfault.com/questions/81746/bypass-ssh-key-file-permission-check/82282#82282) and use mount options based on label to protect your volume.

You can also use access rights to control what can be seen or not if the file system supports permissions (you can change the owner and access rights of the files according to your needs using Finder or command line).